# Reference request on complex line bundles(?)

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

A visiting student a few weeks ago was talking to another student about some mathematics that I had never heard of before and I wrote down something that he wrote on the board.

$$f(z)=1, L=\mathcal{O},\qquad f(z)=z,L=\mathcal{O}(1),\qquad f(z)=z^2,L=\mathcal{O}(2)$$

Where can I read more about this? Sorry if this is vague, it's vague precisely because it is vague to me what this is. I believe these are related to complex line bundles, but I cannot find this $\mathcal{O}$ notation.

Comment: The first $L$ is just the trivial bundle. For each pairs, one might think of $f$ as a section of $L$, where $L$ are lne bundles on $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @JohnMa Do you know a book leaning towards algebraic geometry that covers this sort of content? I have looked at vector bundles before, and projective space, but haven't come across this in an algebraic geometry book.

Comment: (Or any book for that matter, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Huybrechts : *Complex Geometry - An Introduction*

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to cover it!

Comment: You're welcome!